# Can the split screen in Mario Kart 8 be removed?

Tags: mario-kart-8

My fiancé and I recently bought a WiiU and bought Mario Kart 8.  While playing, I use the WiiU's gamepad that has a screen on it and she uses a gamepad plugged into a wii-mote.  I usually play by watching the game on my game pad's screen rather than watching the tv due to a weird depth perception issue I have.

The question I have is, is there a way to tell Mario Kart to only show me on the WiiU game pad and to show my fiancé on the tv?  This way we can both utilize the entire screen that we're using.

Comment: I always wonder this everytime I play, so annoying. I've read it's not possible due to a FPS reason or whatever.

Answer (score 7):

From some light research around Google, the consensus seems to be that it is a highly sought-after feature, yet it was not implemented for Mario Kart 8, for whatever reason. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to split the screen between gamepad and TV. Off-TV play is available for Singleplayer, but when a second, third, or fourth player joins, it is not possible.

Sources: [Here](http://www.gamespot.com/forums/nintendo-fan-club-1000001/mario-kart-8-multi-screen-2-player-option-needed-32020208/) and [here](http://n4g.com/news/1486369/you-cant-play-mario-kart-8-on-the-full-gamepad-screen-while-someone-else-uses-the-full-tv).